# Data augmentation in images in .npy files

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I want to augment the MR image series in .npy files in the MRNet dataset with the keras data generator. But these image sequences don't fit the data generator format and I can't use the function. I converted numpy arrays to images with PIL, how can I increase them?

```
def augment(image):
  aug=[]
  counter = 0
  #plot_img(image)
  for s in range(len(image)):
      counter = counter + 1
      #print("\t augmented img number for this iteration ",counter)
      resized_img = ia.imresize_single_image(image[s], (224, 224))
      rgb_img = add_rgb(resized_img)
      aug.append(rgb_img)
      plot_img(rgb_img)
      heavy_aug_img = heavy_aug(rgb_img)
      #plot_img(heavy_aug_img)
      aug.append(heavy_aug_img)
  aug=np.array(aug)
  return aug

def clear():
  aug= None
  gc.collect()

def heavy_aug(rgb_img) :
  ia.seed(1)

  seq = iaa.Sequential([
      iaa.Fliplr(0.5), # horizontal flips
      iaa.Crop(percent=(0, 0.1)), # random crops
      iaa.LinearContrast((0.75, 1.5)),    
      iaa.AdditiveGaussianNoise(loc=0, scale=(0.0, 0.05*255), per_channel=0.5),

  ], random_order=True) # apply augmenters in random order

  images_aug = seq(images=rgb_img)
  return images_aug
```

Comment: Could you post your code ? What have you tried ?

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan added my codes.